# Android stuck on "Installing" and "Launching App"

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to run my application via Android Studio on a virtual device, or a physical device, my Kotlin app runs the first time, but afterwards I need to disconnect my device each time I want to publish it again.
When I click on "Run App" it just says "Install" an the bottom. When I click it, it says "Launching App". I've had this problem for some time now, and I hope somebody knows the solution for this.
I've tried rebooting and turning USB-debugging off and on. Both work the first time install, just like disconnecting and reconnecting the device. After that however, again it keeps getting stuck on "Installing".

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has happened to me. You might want to invalidate caches and restart once. Also, try checking with some other device too.

Comment: Try by turning on your device's display. Sometime this problem occurred when your device goes to idle state.

Comment: try restarting your device, enabling developer options and usb debugging option, hope it helps

Comment: @M.BilalAsif I tried these things already, and then fix it only one time. After the first install it again stays on "installing"..

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan Tried this and it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 4):

On a virtual device u could try to Open AVD Manager and then click on Wipe Data from dropDown list in actions column

[image]

[image]

Comment: This only fixes it for about three times. Then I have to do this again, or reboot/turn USB debugging off and on again..